# Clear cache programmatically on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: caching, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

One important module (payment) disappears from front office randomly.

I discover that if i clear cache from the back office (see image), the module is back again.

[image]

However, no cache is activated in BO but i need to click on the clear cache button.

So, for now, as i can’t find a solution, i decided to create a cron function to clear cache.

But my function seems to be incomplete because the module doesn’t show after calling this function.
Again, if i clear cache from the  BO (by clicking on the button "clear cache"), the module appears again.

Is something missing in my function ? I use Prestashop 1.6.1.6

Here is my code :

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');

// sécurité pour éviter qu'un robot ou un user appelle le script
$token = Tools::getValue('token');
if (!$token || $token != '169785') {
    die();
}

Tools::clearSmartyCache();
Tools::clearXMLCache();
Media::clearCache();
PrestaShopAutoload::getInstance()->generateIndex();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your function is called?

Comment: yes, because for testing purpose, i call it directly in browser (i will make a CRON after) and after calling the function, the module is still missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `AdminPerformance` controller do:

```
Tools::clearSmartyCache();
Tools::clearXMLCache();
Media::clearCache();
Tools::generateIndex();
```

That's enough :)

Comment: However, I guess you have to find the real issue, what is the payment module that disappear?

Comment: Official CM-CIC / Monetico Paiement https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/paiement-carte-wallet/296-cm-cic-monetico-paiement-en-une-fois.html I have to find the issue but i've seen nothing in module code. I know it is not the best approach, just temporarily

Comment: One weird thing, the module can not be updated in BO (all other modules can be updated). It is the official module developed by Prestashop. Could it be buggy ?

Comment: Sorry, never used that module. It's possible that is bugged, you should open an assistance ticket :)

Comment: Your answer works. My module disappeared, i call the function and it reappears, meaning the cash wash cleared.

Comment: I'm glad that you've resolved, obviously I suggest to you to contact the developers, it's an annoying bug :)